# Type of image indexes

Tags: android, testing, junit, automation, robotium

I'm using Robotium to test Android apk file.
I have a problem with images.
When I want to tap on the image I usually use the index of image like this
solo.clickOnImage(1);
But when this test runs several times, sometime different images are opens with the same index!
Is it possible to use indexes like R.id.add_note or something else, in an Android apk tests?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, but you have to have access to the source code. If you have access to the source code, you need to include the Application Under Test (AUT) in your test programs build path. From there you are able to use the resource id to select specific views (ie text view, image view, list view, ect).

If all you have is the apk, and you don't have access to the source code, then you are limited to blackbox testing.

Hope this helps.